# Woocomerce - Flatsome Theme. Product catalog won't update products per page option

Tags: woocommerce, flatsome

I'm having troubles getting my "Products Per Page"  option under Flatsome >> Woocommerce >> Product Catalog to update.  All the other options I'm able to adjust and it works fine. I have two other websites setup the exact same but this one in particular saves, but it won't actually update the number of products displaued. I've tried the normal Flatsome theme and a child theme and neither will update.  Is there an option in the database that I could update to force this change?  I've been looking but am unable to see one.